# Instance of PDO in class connector

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm working on a project today and i've been working for a while now and i don't see what i do wrong here. Can someone give me the right example.

Thnx a lot!

Connector:

```
class Repository
{
private $connector;

public function __construct(Config $connector)
{
    $this->connector = $connector;
}

public function events()
{
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM digi_gz_parties';
    $dbh_query = $this->connector->getDatabase()->prepare($query);
    $dbh_query->execute();
    $dbh_querys = $dbh_query->fetchAll();

    return $dbh_querys;
}
}
```

Getter:

```
class REST
{
public function getEvents()
{
    require 'logic/Repository.php';

    $event = new Repository();
    $events = $event->events();

    return $events;
}
}
```

Error:
Argument 1 passed to Repository::__construct() must be an instance of Config.

I know i need to give a paramater to the repository but i don't want it, i want only to call the repository without give some paramter.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You didnt pass anything to the Repository constructor, where you type hinted Config class.

Comment: I know, but how can i do it else?

Comment: The `Repository` class requires the `Config` class. The `events()` method you tried to call make use of that `Config` class. What are you gonna replace it with?

Comment: I've changed it sorry.

Comment: As a note if this is an academic project where you need to roll your own code from the ground up, that's not a bad way to do it, but if you're only interested in your objective of building a site you're painfully re-inventing the ORM here. [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) and
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent) are all fully-functional, tested, community supported libraries worth evaluating.

Comment: @tadman there's many people that don't use ORM's and this is definitely a valid way to to implement it.

Comment: @Evert There's often two kinds of people: Those who use ORMs, and those who use ORMs they wrote themselves.

Comment: @tadman I'm aware that some people feel that way, but at the same time it might also be good to consider that there's a significant portion of the developer population that have a very strong disdain for ORMs. I'm not among them, but completely ignoring one side of the argument is not doing anything in your favor.

Comment: @Evert I'm just making suggestions here because a lot of people fall victim to old tutorials that pre-date modern ORMs. Making a decision based on all available information is always better than one out of ignorance. Sometimes you don't need an ORM, but for someone new at SQL and PHP, they give a lot of structure and cohesion to your code. If you've got enough experience there's other ways to do that, but it can often be more work.

Comment: @tadman I don't disagree with that point at all.

Comment: thanks a lot for your anwsers!

Comment: I've created this code without any tutorial. But i update my code and use an interface and extends the Config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `Repository::__construct()` to have a default `$connector` to `null`:

```
public function __construct(Config $connector = null)
{
    $this->connector = $connector;
}
```

That way, if you instanciate your object without any parameter, like you do here, it will default to `null`. The only downside of that is that, now, you have to be extra careful when using `$this->connector` inside your `Repository` class and remember it could be null.

For exemple, here, the second line of your `events()` method is not going to work, because you lack the proper configuration to connect to your database.

Comment: So why to change the constructor signature if it leads to breaking other methods?

Comment: Because it is what the OP question is about: having a possibilty to instanciate the object with no parameters.

Comment: The question is correct, i was to bussy with coding today and didn't see my childly fould. I've change my code and work with an interface and deploy the constructor as protected in the repository.